Continuity of operator $T$ and $T^{-1}$.
Let $T$ be the linear operator defined by
$$ (Tf)(x) = x\int_0^x  f(t)  dt $$
on the space $C[0,1]$, with the supremum norm. Check
$1.$ The continuity of the operator $T$
and
$2.$ whether $T^{-1}$ exists on the range of $T$ and is continuous.
I attempted it as follows:
First, we calculate the norm of $T(f)$:
$$ \|T(f)\| = \left\| \int_0^x x f(t) \, dt \right\| = \sup_x \left| \int_0^x x f(t) \, dt \right| $$
By the properties of the integral, we have:
$ \left| \int_0^x x f(t) \, dt \right| \leq \int_0^1 |f(t)| \, dt \leq \sup_{t \in [0,1]} |f(t)| = \|f\| $
Thus, $T$ is bounded (continuous).
Now, according to me, $T^{-1}$ is not continuous. If it were continuous, then we would have:
$ \|T(f)\| \geq K\|f\| $
However, this is not the case. For example, if we take $f(x) = x^n$, then:
$ \|T(f)\| = \left\| \int_0^x x t^n  dt \right\| = \left\| \frac{x^{n+2}}{n+1} \right\| $
Which shows that $\|T(f)\| \geq K\|f\|$ does not hold since $\| \frac{x^{n+2}}{n+1}\|= \|\frac{1}{n+1}\|$ is not greater than or equal to $K$, for any fixed $K>0$.
Therefore, I conclude that $T$ is continuous, but $T^{-1}$ (if it exists) is not continuous.
Please suggest if there is a more easy way or where I made a mistake. Thank you.

Is $T(f)$ supposed to be the integral of $tf(t)$, or the integral of $f(t)$ multiplied by $x$? The notation seems a bit unclear to me.

@DavidGao Its $\int_0^x xf(t)dt.$

Instead of saying 'does not hold since $\frac{x^{n+2}}{n+1}$ is not greater than or equal to $K$'  you should say $|\frac {x^{n+2}} {n+1}|=\frac 1  {n+1}$ and 'does not hold since $\frac{1}{n+1}$ is not greater than or equal to $K$.

The LHS should be $T(f)(x)$

@neelkanth That's why I said it's a bit unclear. I would have written $x \int_0^x f(t) , dt$. Writing $x$ in the integrand makes it seem like a typo, and that it should have been $t$. (Either case though, $T(f)$ is continuously differentiable for any $f \in C[0, 1]$, so $T$ is not surjective. So $T^{-1}$ does not exist in the first place.)

@DavidGao Yes it seems unclear but in question it was same as written .

@DavidGao Edit the question and  continuity of $T^{-1}$ is on the range of $T.$ $T$ is one one so inverse exists . Thank you .

@neelkanth Then your approach is already quite simple. The argument still needs a bit clearing up, but it seems already reasonably easy. Anything else I could think of uses quite high-powered machinery.

@DavidGao Thank you .
